# Volume of intersection of a convex polytope with general affine space

Tags: convex-polytopes, geometric-measure-theory

This question generalizes [(this question)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116784/volume-of-intersection-of-a-convex-polytope-with-an-affine-space) on the same site.

Let $\Delta^{n}$ denote the $n$-dimensional simplex in $n$ dimensions.
That is, $\Delta^{n}$ is the convex closure of the origin
and the $n$ canonical unit vectors.

Let $A$ be an affine $k$-dimensional subspace in $\mathbb R^{n}$ whose
intersection with $\Delta^{n}$ is non-empty.

How can we compute the $k$-dimensional volume and the barycenter of
$\Delta^{n} \cap A$? We may suppose that $A$ is given as the intersection of $n-k$ hyperplanes. I am looking for a closed form expression - for $A$ fixed, the $k$-dimensional volume and the barycenter should vary in an understandable manner over the interior of the simplex.

Comment: Up to homothetie and translation, every polytope $P$ in $\bf R^k$ appears like this. Let $P$ be defined by $u_i(x) \geq a_i$, for $1\leq i\leq n$. The $u_i$ are linear forms, i.e. elements in $(\bf R^k)^*$. Now consider the linear map $U : (\bf R^n)^* \to \bf (R^k)^*$ defined by $\pi (e^*_i)= u_i$. Its transposed map  $U^t : \bf R^k \to \bf R^n$ send $P$ into the intersection of the cone $y_i\geq a_i$ with $U^t(\bf R)^n$.